# How to setup windows authentication for empty ASP Net application template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create web application using Web API 2 which uses the windows authentication for in company use. However I don't want to use MVC nor Web Forms. Is there any way that empty ASP net template could be set up to so the user will not be required to log in, while I could code my client in framework  of my choice ?

The users will only access the app from company PC computers where they login using the windows domain.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use MVC. Quote "To create an application that uses Integrated Windows authentication, select the “Intranet Application” template in the MVC 4 project wizard."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing, and ended up adding having to add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc Nuget package to my project to get it working correctly.  You don't have to use MVC, just adding the package to your project will be enough.

Then just add the following to your web.config file and you should be good.

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

If debugging in Visual Studio, be sure to set Windows Authentication to Enabled in the Properties window.  This is not set when you create an empty project.